# Не отображается заголовок при репосте в вк

Tags: javascript, битрикс, share, ya-share2

Есть [страница](http://web.archive.org/web/20171121220306/https://sllife.ru/news/intensiv_mirovoy_dekupazh_v_noyabre_/). На ней стоит блок «Поделиться» от Яндекс.

При репосте в вк получается такая беда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Open Graph и schema.org стоят, но может неправильно настроено? Стоит битрикс.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете старую версию блока. Её поддержка прекращена, а значит, на полную работоспособность рассчитывать не стоит.

Разработчики рекомендуют переходить на актуальную (вторую) версию.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо)